# Putting a line underneath a word in three part table

Tags: threeparttable

I cant seem to fix this small issue where the line underneath the word "MS-DNS" is aligned to the left instead of right underneath the word. Here is the LaTeX code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\caption{\textbf{Filtered errors MS-DNS model and extensions with macro 
factors}}
 \label{table:filtered_errors_macro}
 \centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{\linewidth}
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\toprule 
\hline 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-DNS} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-DRA} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-TVTP}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MS-DNS-X} \\ 
 \cmidrule(l){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11}
Maturity & {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.} 
         & {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.}
     & {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.}
     & {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.} \\ 
\midrule
3      & -0.066 & 0.063 & -0.070 & 0.345 & -0.139 & 0.330  & -0.229 & 1.608 \\
6      &  0.027 & 0.047 &  0.003 & 0.325 & -0.049 & 0.257  & -0.327 & 3.440 \\
12     & 0.076  & 0.072 &  0.037 & 0.334 & 0.014  & 0.226  & -0.556 & 6.140 \\
24     & 0.025  & 0.025 & -0.002 & 0.330 & 0.020  & 0.228  & -0.898 & 8.853 \\
36     & -0.034 & 0.037 & -0.038 & 0.324 & 0.012  & 0.227  & -1.059 & 9.544 \\
60     & -0.074 & 0.055 & -0.068 & 0.314 & 0.000  & 0.225  & -1.107 & 8.643 \\
84     & -0.032 & 0.026 & -0.050 & 0.304 & 0.010  & 0.222  & -1.013 & 7.118 \\
120    & 0.079  & 0.057 & 0.009 & 0.305 & 0.044  & 0.229  & -0.834 & 5.276\\
\addlinespace
Mean   & 0.000  & 0.048 & -0.022 & 0.323 & -0.011 & 0.243  & -0.753 & 6.328 \\
Median & -0.004 & 0.051 & -0.020 & 0.324 & 0.011  & 0.228  & -0.866 & 6.629 \\
Lower  &        &       &  5     &  0    & 5      & 0         &  0     & 0     
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\smallskip

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
 \item Note: This table reports filtered errors from the MS-DNS model and its 
extensions with macro factors. The filtered errors are defined as the residuals 
of the measurement equation and are formed by taking the difference of the 
observed yield and its filtered estimate obtained by the Kim filter. For each 
maturity, I present the mean and standard deviation (\textit{Std. dev.}). 
Moreover, I show the mean, median and number of maturities for which the mean 
of the extended macro model is lower than the mean of the MS-DNS model in 
absolute terms (\textit{Lower}).
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output of the LaTeX code hopefully makes clear what is the problem:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
\cmidrule(l){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11}
```

to

```
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
```

The numbers in braces correspond to the columns each rule should span. Your columns go from 1 to 9, so `\cmidrule(l){10-11}` gives an error about extra alignment tabs being inserted, which is TeX's way of saying your numbers are "out of bounds".

The new output is as expected:

[image]

*EDIT:* As leandriis pointed out in the comments, you should also replace

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
```

by one of

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
```

to reserve extra space for the minus signs (in either all or just the "Mean" columns) and thus getting rid of the `Overfull \hbox` warnings.

Comment: You might also want to include that `\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}` should be replaced by `\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}` in order to get rid of the overfull box warnings.

Comment: Could you explain why that works? Both formats seem identical to me, but the latter makes the table a bit wider.

Comment: The former variant does not take into account the `-` signs in the "mean" columns. One can change that by including this as follows: `table-format=-1.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `\cmidrule{2-3}` and so on: with that input you get an error message about “too many columns”; TeX tries to recover as best as it can, but it should be fixed.

Rather than leaving the table to get past the margins, I'd typeset it `\small`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]

\caption{Filtered errors MS-DNS model and extensions with macro factors}
\label{table:filtered_errors_macro}

\begin{threeparttable}
\centering

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\toprule 
Maturity
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-DNS} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-DRA} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-TVTP}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MS-DNS-X} \\ 
 \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.} 
& {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.}
& {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.}
& {Mean} & {Std.\ dev.} \\ 
\midrule
3      & -0.066 & 0.063 & -0.070 & 0.345 & -0.139 & 0.330  & -0.229 & 1.608 \\
6      &  0.027 & 0.047 &  0.003 & 0.325 & -0.049 & 0.257  & -0.327 & 3.440 \\
12     & 0.076  & 0.072 &  0.037 & 0.334 & 0.014  & 0.226  & -0.556 & 6.140 \\
24     & 0.025  & 0.025 & -0.002 & 0.330 & 0.020  & 0.228  & -0.898 & 8.853 \\
36     & -0.034 & 0.037 & -0.038 & 0.324 & 0.012  & 0.227  & -1.059 & 9.544 \\
60     & -0.074 & 0.055 & -0.068 & 0.314 & 0.000  & 0.225  & -1.107 & 8.643 \\
84     & -0.032 & 0.026 & -0.050 & 0.304 & 0.010  & 0.222  & -1.013 & 7.118 \\
120    & 0.079  & 0.057 & 0.009 & 0.305 & 0.044  & 0.229  & -0.834 & 5.276\\
\addlinespace
Mean   & 0.000  & 0.048 & -0.022 & 0.323 & -0.011 & 0.243  & -0.753 & 6.328 \\
Median & -0.004 & 0.051 & -0.020 & 0.324 & 0.011  & 0.228  & -0.866 & 6.629 \\
Lower  &        &       &  5     &  0    & 5      & 0         &  0     & 0     
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
 \item \hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Note: This table reports filtered errors from the MS-DNS model and its 
extensions with macro factors. The filtered errors are defined as the residuals 
of the measurement equation and are formed by taking the difference of the 
observed yield and its filtered estimate obtained by the Kim filter. For each 
maturity, I present the mean and standard deviation (\textit{Std.\ dev.}). 
Moreover, I show the mean, median and number of maturities for which the mean 
of the extended macro model is lower than the mean of the MS-DNS model in 
absolute terms (\textit{Lower}).
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can possibly avoid `\small` by reducing the column headers:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]

\caption{Filtered errors MS-DNS model and extensions with macro factors}
\label{table:filtered_errors_macro}

\begin{threeparttable}
\centering

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\toprule 
Maturity
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-DNS} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-DRA} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-TVTP}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MS-DNS-X} \\ 
 \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& {M} & {SD} 
& {M} & {SD}
& {M} & {SD}
& {M} & {SD} \\ 
\midrule
3      & -0.066 & 0.063 & -0.070 & 0.345 & -0.139 & 0.330  & -0.229 & 1.608 \\
6      &  0.027 & 0.047 &  0.003 & 0.325 & -0.049 & 0.257  & -0.327 & 3.440 \\
12     & 0.076  & 0.072 &  0.037 & 0.334 & 0.014  & 0.226  & -0.556 & 6.140 \\
24     & 0.025  & 0.025 & -0.002 & 0.330 & 0.020  & 0.228  & -0.898 & 8.853 \\
36     & -0.034 & 0.037 & -0.038 & 0.324 & 0.012  & 0.227  & -1.059 & 9.544 \\
60     & -0.074 & 0.055 & -0.068 & 0.314 & 0.000  & 0.225  & -1.107 & 8.643 \\
84     & -0.032 & 0.026 & -0.050 & 0.304 & 0.010  & 0.222  & -1.013 & 7.118 \\
120    & 0.079  & 0.057 & 0.009 & 0.305 & 0.044  & 0.229  & -0.834 & 5.276\\
\addlinespace
Mean   & 0.000  & 0.048 & -0.022 & 0.323 & -0.011 & 0.243  & -0.753 & 6.328 \\
Median & -0.004 & 0.051 & -0.020 & 0.324 & 0.011  & 0.228  & -0.866 & 6.629 \\
Lower  &        &       &  5     &  0    & 5      & 0         &  0     & 0     
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
\item \hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Note: This table reports filtered errors from 
the MS-DNS model and its extensions with macro factors. The filtered errors are 
defined as the residuals of the measurement equation and are formed by taking 
the difference of the observed yield and its filtered estimate obtained by the 
Kim filter. For each maturity, I present the mean (M,~\textit{Mean}) and standard 
deviation (SD,~\textit{Std.\ dev.}). Moreover, I show the mean, median and number 
of maturities for which the mean of the extended macro model is lower than the 
mean of the MS-DNS model in absolute terms (\textit{Lower}).
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]